# Share options application link in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a share button in my app on which when user click it shows a popup message to share the link of my application to different social sites, but when u click it shows only Facebook icon to share the link.How can I get different other sites access like Gmail, Twitter, Instagram, Yahoo and WhatsApp. This is my code

```
NSString *texttoshare = @"myURL"; //this is your text string to share
NSArray *activityItems = @[texttoshare];
UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypePrint];
[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:TRUE completion:nil];
```

[image]

Comment: its the simulator, you need to check this in device

Comment: yet i have no access to device , Is my code is right? It will show other options in mobile?@Anbu.Karthik

Comment: yes @Anbu.Karthik is right.

Comment: your code is right